# Could anyone explain Desk.com?

Tags: desk.com

Could anybody please explain about `Desk.com`? I mean what is the difference between `Service Cloud` and `Desk.com`? What features does it have? If someone could just throw some light on it, it'd be great.

Also, the documentation on `Desk.com` was pretty vague hence the question here.

Answer (score 2):

Meredith here from Salesforce. Thanks for your question. Desk.com and Service Cloud are both support offerings from Salesforce.  Desk.com is an out-of-the-box helpdesk with basic functionality like workflow, case management, and reporting.  It helps fast-growing businesses deliver awesome customer service. If you're struggling managing support with email and spreadsheets, Desk.com is a good place to start.

Service Cloud is a fully customizable solution that you can use to design your ideal support process. With more advanced functionality, you can further automate processes, surface key knowledge articles, and connect one-to-one with every customer.

If you have questions about which is best for you or want more detail, let me know and we'll be in touch.

Answer (score 1):

Desk.com is less capable than Service Cloud. At the last company I worked, we considered it for an internal help desk application for users to get IT-related help. Pricing was better for this purpose as we didn't want to pay for Service Cloud licenses for everyone in the company.

You may have found this already, but here is a link to the Desk.com FAQ that has some good information: http://www.salesforce.com/desk/faq/

Here's another site that has some more in-depth history and comparison of the two: [The Difference between Desk.com and Service Cloud.](https://www.getapp.com/blog/difference-between-desk-com-and-salesforce-service-cloud-help-desk-software/)